# Kafka Streams API: Session Window incompatible types

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-producer-api

I have the following snippet:

```
groupedStream.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(config.joinWindowSeconds)).grace(Duration.ZERO));

KTable<byte[], byte[]> mergedTable =
        groupedStream
            .reduce((aggregateValue, newValue) -> {
              try {
                Map<String, String> recentMap = MAPPER.readValue(new String(newValue), HashMap.class);
                Map<String, String> aggregateMap = MAPPER.readValue(new String(newValue), HashMap.class);
                aggregateMap.forEach(recentMap::putIfAbsent);
                newValue = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(recentMap).getBytes();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.warn("Couldn't aggregate key grouped stream\n", e);
              }
              return newValue;
            }, Materialized.with(Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray()))
            .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()));
```

I am getting the following compilation exception:

```
Error:(164, 63) java: incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Suppressed<? super byte[]>
```

I know that if I inline the `windowedBy` like so:

```
        KTable<Windowed<byte[]>, byte[]> mergedTable =
                groupedStream
                        .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(config.joinWindowSeconds)).grace(Duration.ZERO))
                        .reduce((aggregateValue, newValue) -> {
                            try {
                                Map<String, String> recentMap = MAPPER.readValue(new String(newValue), HashMap.class);
                                Map<String, String> aggregateMap = MAPPER.readValue(new String(newValue), HashMap.class);
                                aggregateMap.forEach(recentMap::putIfAbsent);
                                newValue = MAPPER.writeValueAsString(recentMap).getBytes();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                LOG.warn("Couldn't aggregate key grouped stream\n", e);
                            }
                            return newValue;
                        }, Materialized.with(Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray()))
                        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()));
```

It works, but I am not sure how to separate and split those two...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two issues here.

The first issue is that [KGroupedStream.windowedBy(SessionWindows)](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html#windowedBy-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.SessionWindows-) returns an instance of a `SessionWindowedKStream<K, V>` and in your first example

> `groupedStream.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(config.joinWindowSeconds)).grace(Duration.ZERO));`

You are not capturing the returned `SessionWindowedKStream` in a variable.

The second issue is in your first code example you have

> `KTable<byte[], byte[]> mergedTable`

when it should be

> `KTable<Windowed<byte[]>, byte[]> mergedTable`

as it is in your second example.

If you change the code to

```
SessionWindowedKStream<byte[], byte[]> sessionWindowedKStream = groupedStream.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(config.joinWindowSeconds)).grace(Duration.ZERO));

KTable<Windowed<byte[]>, byte[]> mergedTable = 
      sessionWindowedKStream
                .reduce((aggregateValue, newValue) -> {...
```

Then it should compile fine.

HTH 
Bill

Comment: The solution works, and it does work. I wasn't sure if maybe the serdes were wrong because when I tried it previously, before trying inlined solution, I was getting the following problem for some reason:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61883482/kafka-streams-api-session-window-exception

Comment: I read your comment, I'm not sure, but I'll take a look into it.

Comment: I was also speculating that normally stores its state in "a file somewhere", and once the right kind of WindowedStore (or some SerDe somewhere is not serialized properly) is set and persisted, it doesn't throw an error anymore.